# How to compare two rows with same column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have data like below. I need to compare ATTRIBUTE1_TXT based on PART_KEY_ID. If both the date is same, i need that PART_KEY_ID.

```
PART_KEY_ID ATTRIBUTE1_TXT
504277          JUL 2019 (201)
504277          JUL 2019 (201)
5493605         JUL 2019 (201)
5493605         JUN 2018 (191)
4585233         JUL 2019 (201)
4585233         JUL 2019 (201)
6192893         JUL 2019 (201)
6192893         JUN 2018 (191)
```

so output should be.

```
PART_KEY_ID
504277
4585233
```

Comment: What if there are more than two rows and some match but others do not?

Comment: i am sorry.. But in ATTRIBUTE1_TXT there are other values also present

Comment: . . It is only possible to answer the question that you have asked.  In this question, you seem to want parts that have only one value for the attribute -- and there are multiple answers.  I would suggest that you accept one of those answers and ask a *new* question with more appropriate sample data and description of what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, i have add one more condition to ATTRIBUTE1_TXT and it work well.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select PART_KEY_ID 
from your_table
group by PART_KEY_ID 
having count(distinct ATTRIBUTE1_TXT) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
select part_key_id
from t
group by part_key_id
having min(ATTRIBUTE1_TXT) = max(ATTRIBUTE1_TXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select PART_KEY_ID from(select ATTRIBUTE1_TXT ,max(PART_KEY_ID),count(*) from table  group by ATTRIBUTE1_TXT having count(*) >1)t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   --this will work 
  --if you got three similar  ATTRIBUTE1_TXT for one PART_KEY_ID you can replace 
  ----having count(*)=2 in cte to having count(*)=3

   ;with cte as (
    select count(*) c,PART_KEY_ID,ATTRIBUTE1_TXT
    from table
    group by PART_KEY_ID,ATTRIBUTE1_TXT
    having count(*)=2
    ) 

    select PART_KEY_ID
    from cte
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query, I think it should satisfy your need.

```
SELECT PART_KEY_ID
FROM table_name
GROUP BY PART_KEY_ID, ATTRIBUTE1_TXT
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```